# Are questions with no votes considered not well-received?

Tags: support, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

I went to ask a question today and received this warning:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

Upon looking at my question history, I see that I have no up votes or down votes on any of my questions. I have read the "How to Ask A Question" sections and do my best to be clear in my questions, even if they may seem novice. Am I in danger of being blocked simply because of no up votes, or is there something else that I can do?

Comment: Do you have deleted poorly received questions.

Comment: I honestly don't remember. Obviously, if my question was bad, I would delete it to eliminate non-productive questions, but I can't imagine that it would be a lot.

Comment: In general, I try to contribute positively to the best of my ability.

Comment: Then apparently you have enough poorly received deleted content to result in this warning, and need to ensure that your future contributions do well in order to continue contributing.

Comment: You can see your deleted recent questions with a link at the bottom of the questions section of your profile.

Comment: Just for the reference:  the question you're asking isn't *bad*.  I'm not assuming anything about deleted questions or the like.  I'm not making any insinuations into the quality of your past questions.  It's a question worthy of asking.  All I wanted to say on it, really.